# Using buttons inside a textarea in ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I want to place buttons inside a textarea as follows: 
When the user marks text in the textarea, a small toolbar of two or three buttons should appear above that text and should disappear once it is unmarked.

My question would be whether a) that is possible in ckeditor at all and b) if buttons from ckeditor's own toolbar can be used in such a toolbar or if I would have to create custom buttons.

Comment: Do you have any code you tried so far,coz your question not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="test">
I love Programming
</textarea>
<button id="btn">alert selection</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert(test.value.substring(test.selectionStart,
                                    test.selectionEnd));

});
```

Hope this will be helped to you,you can make changes as your requirement :) if not sorry for me,
you can make variable and assign this value or use this value to button value

```
(test.value.substring(test.selectionStart,test.selectionEnd));
```

and please remember also i'm not understood your question properly.
Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/5kq4yecz/5/
Good luck!!!

Comment: I am actually looking for a button (or several buttons) that only appears above a text piece in the text area if I click on that text piece and only while it is marked.

Comment: have you check my code??it provides selected value from textfield as a alert message :) you can use that value to button text , and please mark my answer as useful if you get any idea or help from it,if not sorry dear ;(

Comment: Yes, but that is not why I am looking for. In your example, the button has a fixed location and is always visible. What I need is a button that appears dynamically above a certain part of the text when I mark that text and disappears when I unmark it.

Comment: sorry @jgpt , i can't help to you this time .coz i also too complex your problem,i'll try but don't sure.ok